# android notification always relaunches activity

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

First time poster here, please excuse my lengthy post - I want to provide all the necessary info.

I am trying to achieve the coveted resume from clicking on notification functionality, but I am having some difficulties.  First off, details(code below):

1. Project Properties

   ```
   Android Developer Tools Build: v21.1.0-569685
   Project Build Target : 4.2.2
   Platofrm : 4.2.2
   API Level : 17
   SDK Target : 17
   SDK min : 14

   Android Device Chooser : Android Device : Nexus 4
   ```
2. *MyApp* launches *MyAppService* via startService
3. *MyAppService*'s onStartCommand function uses NotificationCompat.Builder object to create a bar in the pull down notification.

The behavior I am trying to achieve :

1. Launch an app with a notification bar entry(e.g. Mail)
2. Start MyApp(this will also start MyAppService)
3. Pull down the notification bar and select MyAppService(yes, MyApp is currently on screen
4. Notification bar should just roll up w/o doing anything

What I am noticing is that MyApp will minimize out, and a new instance of MyApp will maximize(similar transition to when the app is being launched).  I expect this behavior when I select on MyAppService when I have Mail app on top(Mail app to minimize and for MyApp to maximize).

There have been many code snippets and suggestions but I can't seem to get it to work; so here are the contents of my files :

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/eyeview"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MyApp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".service.MyAppService"
        android:label="MyAppService">
    </service>
</application>
```

MyApp/MainActivity.java

```
public static Intent serviceIntent;
public static Messenger clientMessenger;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    if (getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT)
    {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...
    [stuff specific to app, like setting up Fragments]
    ...

    MainActivity.serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyAppService.class);
    MainActivity.serviceIntent.putExtra("clientMessenger", clientMessenger);
    startService(MainActivity.serviceIntent);
}
```

MyAppService.java

```
@Override
private int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder ncB = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_app)
        .setContentTitle("MyAppService")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app);

    ncB.setContentText("Click to start MyApp");

    Intent nIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    nIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    nIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(nIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int nId = 1;
    Notification notification = ncB.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    notificationManager.notify(nId, notification); 

    sendMessengerToClient(intent);

    startForeground(nId, ncB.build());

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

I hope I included all the enough information - I've been tweaking the code I got from SO just to see if this would work - in EVERY case, the topmost application minimizes out to black screen, and MyApp would maximize and MainActivity.java's onCreate function gets called.

I just want the notification pulldown to just scroll up if MyApp is already topmost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not really a good idea to have a notification for your own app when it's the topmost activity; notifications are for informing the user about something related to your app when something else is in front of it. I would suggest that you cancel any notifications for your app when its activities are on top.

Comment: Oh and also, you don't need to call `notify()` yourself if you're also using `startForeground()`; the latter call will take care of posting the notification.

Comment: hey @dsandler, the notification is actually maintained by `MyAppService.java`, which is a service that is launched when `MyApp` starts up.

Comment: Continuing...

I've been reading a lot of the "my android app does not resume on click of Notification" type posts and they don't work for me.

I want to launch a service(`MyAppService`) that will be running and performing scheduled tasks and the `MainActivity.java` will be a GUI that the enduser can launch to add/edit/remove scheduled tasks.

Comment: OK, then in that case you might want to make your service not a foreground service; that way you can cancel and re-post the notification when the activity shows and hides.

Comment: I feel I like I need to study some android tutorials on how to the notification shade just roll up if the app is currently launched and is topmost.  In every case, it seems to terminate and relaunch(I see the transition animation of the current window going away and a new instance popup.

Answer (score 4):

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, 
    notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

By setting `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flags you can achieve this I guess. It won't create your activity if its already running.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the answer have by Shashika worked but in a weird fashion. I HAD TO RESTART THE PHONE! :)